# Can't figure out this leak

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks

```
SettingsView *settings = [[SettingsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
settings.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:settings animated:YES];
settings = nil;
[settings release];
```

Instruments claims that the following line is leaking

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:settings animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to release `settings` before setting it to `nil`, not after!

What you're doing now is the same as:

```
settings = nil;
[nil release];
```

So the -release is being sent to `nil`, not to your `SettingsView` object. (And sending any message to `nil` is a NOOP).

Answer (score 0):

Right.  Since 'settings' was never set up with a @property and @synthesize, setting it to nil just erases the memory address it is holding.

If you had set it up with 
`@property (nonatomic, retain) SettingsView *settings;`

then a later call to `settings = nil;`

would also send a `[settings release]` message.

Comment: FWIW, the statement `settings = nil` will not call the accessor setter method even if settings is a declared property; it will simply set the ivar to nil. You'd need to do `self.settings = nil;` to get the behavior you're describing.